# Possible outcomes of not using a current limiting resistor in this LED driver?

Tags: led-driver

I have [this](http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/31FL3731.pdf) LED Driver in my hand.
I would like to run my LEDs at the maximum brightness possible - meaning I am thinking of excluding the R_EXT (current limiting resistor pin) connection to a resistor.

The datasheet (page 18) doesn't say much other than

```
The recommended minimum value of REXT is 18kΩ, or
it may cause a large current.
```

So I don't know if it is ok or not. Will I hear high pitched noise because the driver is over-driven? Will it *kill* my IC and possibly LEDs in the long term?

Comment: If the manufacturer can't guarantee what would happen I would not meddle with it. It might not kill one unit and kill the next one. It might not kill it immediatly but maybe in 6 months. Who knows.

Answer (score 4):

I<sub>OUT</sub> is specified to be 34mA per matrix line, and note 1 states:

> The average current of each LED is I<sub>OUT</sub>/10.5.

As such, if the current is too much higher than 34mA / 10.5 = 3.24mA then the device may become damaged. This corresponds to a resistance of 64.7V / 3.24mA = 19.97kohm.

Answer (score 3):

This chip uses a switched current mirror approach to control the LED current. The current you suck out of pin 6 (R_EXT) is reflected (to some nominal ratio and accuracy) in the output current.

If you did something like shorting pin 6 to ground (0\$\Omega\$) that alone could damage the chip. Running at higher than recommended current could result in overheating or long-term unreliability due to temperature or electromigration effects.

They probably have not designed this chip for an enormous lifetime in the first place (it's aimed at typically short lived consumer applications), so I suggest you stick the **recommended** value and concentrate on finding a brighter set of LEDs, or use another drive method if you need more brightness.

Answer (score 2):

REXT is not inside the power path, so it is not a current limiting resistor.

Instead, it is used to create a comparison value that is used as a reference for the actual current limiters (either in the row or the column drivers). If you run this out of spec, anything may happen, including having no current limit (fries the LEDs) or having a current limit close to zero (no output).

It is unlikely to damage the driver IC itself, I think (everything connected there internally has a fairly large impedance), but since it's a pointless configuration that isn't worth much.

Answer (score -2):

Small transistors can melt themselves in under a microsecond.

The thermal Tau of 10micron cube of silicon is 1.14 microseconds.
The thermal Tau of 1 micron cube of silicon is 11.4 nanoseconds.

Avoid shorts.
-------edit--------
How quickly does death arrive? Use specific-heat of silicon at 2picoJoule/deg C/micron^2. The volume of 10micron cube is 1,000 micron^2, thus its specific-heat is 2 nanojoules/dec C. What is the heating rate? Assume 100mA * 1 volt, thus 0.1joule/second. Or 0.1mJ/millisecond. Or 0.1uJ/microsecond. Which is 100nanoJ/uS.

In 1uS, that 10micron square transistor (Bip or MOS), 10micron deep, heats up by 100nJ/2nJ = 50 degree C. In 1uS. Or 500 degree C in 10uSecond. Don't do that.

Comment: Hey, i just wanted to let you know why I down-voted. I feel that your answer goes way off on a tangent, which is extremely detailed for no apparent reason and doesn't answer the original question other than "physics and heat means don't do that". You should provide a well structured answer that answers the question as practically as possible, including only relevant information. See the other answers people have given for an example of useful answers.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the downvote. My answer provides full details in understanding an ignored silicon phenomena. Does stackexchange not want that kind of detail?

Comment: The answer is way out on relevance. It's great information to know, but not the right time to use it. The user needs guidance interpreting the datasheet and the method of operation of their IC, and how the current-sense resistor affects the operation of the IC and potential risks.